# How do I set-up user quotas limits on the file system?

Tags: users

I need to set-up a local file system limit of 2 - 5 GB per user. How do i configure that limit?

Answer (score 0):

How to configure a quota for the root partition affecting a single user:

Open a terminal. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>.

Run it:

```
sudo -i
nano /etc/fstab
```

In the open file, you must add to the assembly line of partition, root in this case, the parameters usrjquota=aquota.user,grpjquota=aquota.group,jqfmt=vfsv0.

Example:

Change

```
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=c676ae51-cb6f-4c0e-b4a9-76850aafa1d6 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

To

```
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=c676ae51-cb6f-4c0e-b4a9-76850aafa1d6 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro,usrjquota=aquota.user,grpjquota=aquota.group,jqfmt=vfsv0  0    1
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.

This activates quotas by user and/or group ID using the “vfsv0″ quota format, using 32 bit for UIDs/GIDs, 64 bit for space usage, and 32 bit for inode usage in this case.

Continue running:

```
mount -o remount /
apt-get update
apt-get install quota quotatool
quotacheck -vagum
```

To set a quota, you must use the setquota command:

```
setquota [ -rm ] [ -u | -g ] [ -F quotaformat ] name block-softlimit block-hardlimit inode-softlimit inode-hardlimit -a | filesystem
```

Example setting a quota for a specific user:

```
sudo -i
setquota -u -F vfsv0 UseR 2097152 2097152 1000000 1000000 /
```

Affect the root file system /.

Limit disk usage for the user UseR to 2 GB.

Limit the number of inodes for the user UseR to 1000000.

Not distinguish between hard and soft limits.

Use the vfsv0 quota format.